# GreenDAO 3 with Android studio

Tags: android-studio, greendao, greendao-generator, greendao3

I used to work with GreenDAO in Android Studio, in 2.1.0 version, to include GreenDAO to my project, I will create a generator module. In the module's build.gradle, I will add this line.

```
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.1.0'
```

Then I will define my entities, run the gradle build task and the entities will be generated.
Now I hear about GreenDAO version 3. I can't find a full tutorial which show me the full process like version 2.1.0. In their [homepage](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/how-to-get-started/), I can see a short example about notation, but don't know how to "add greenDAO 3 support" to my project" at all.
Could you give me a detail?

Comment: read the complete documentation in the offical greendao site that you have linked. There is all you need for a full comprension of greendao 3 library.

Comment: My recommend is read the Introduction of GreenDAO 3 (http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/introduction/) and check the DaoExample (https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/tree/master/examples)